# Compare two database using database first apporach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I want to compare two databases using Database First apporach. Here is it what I want to do, I will create two new items (database connection using Enity ADO.Net..), Now I have two DbContext one for source database and other for destination database.

Now I want pick one DbContext instance and iterate over all the tables it holds, when I get reference to a single table then I want to iterete over all of its columns.

My questions are:

1. Using Database first approach when whe have reference to DbContext, how to iterate over all of its tables. And when we have reference to its table then how to iterate over all of its columns?
2. Is there any other easy way to do this (means comparing two databases tables)?

If I am using a database with two tables(Person, Employee) then I don't want to hardcode these names into the code. I want to read/use tables names form the dbContext. B'cause this app should compare any two databases(only tables).

Sub-problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946794/display-data-from-all-the-tables-using-database-first-approach

Anybody there??? help me....

Comment: Does "iterate over all of its tables then iterate over all of its columns" means "getting all table names in both DBs then get all data inside them to compare each other"? If your DBs contain huge amount of records, I prefer batch operation with one-by-one comparison to returning all records and compare them simultaneously (think of memory usage issues).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Does "iterate over all of its tables then iterate over all of its columns" means "getting all table names in both DBs then get all data inside them to compare each other"? YES

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  If your DBs contain huge amount of records, I prefer batch operation with one-by-one comparison to returning all records and compare them simultaneously (think of memory usage issues). Yes I will do it in batch operation but I don't know how to get information about tables and tables-fields.

Comment: If you want to compare both databases instances, this will take quite a while for bigger databases. For the schema information however, you can use the database metadata (dependent on DBMS)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Thank you. But I want to use only entity framework. Can I get tables information from DbContext, DbSet, or othe objects ???

Comment: you could try to calculate your schema from the objects and modelbuilder via reflection, however this could be a rather complex task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql management object for this . Some implementation samples can be found

Look here
https://dbcompare.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=default

or Look at
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool